# Custom Post Type only display items created by user

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles

I've used the following tutorial to register a new post type and restrict a custom role to that post type:

http://3.7designs.co/blog/2014/08/restricting-access-to-custom-post-types-using-roles-in-wordpress/

What do I need to do with my capabilities to have the user role only be able to view the [custom post type] items that they themselves create and not be able to view items created by others?

I do plan to also create another user role that will be able to view items created by anybody.

Comment: On the front end? Back end? Both? Please clarify the question

Comment: @s_ha_dum On the back end.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of coming up with this functionality myself and re-inventing the wheel I'm using the built-in functionality that makes a post 'private'.

By using this I've had to force all posts to be private, I've done so using the `wp_insert_post_data` filter:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', array($this, 'post_data_save'), 10, 2);
```

And my method:

```
public function post_data_save($post){
    if($post['post_type'] == 'my_custom_post_type'){
        switch($post['post_status']){
            case 'publish': $post['post_status'] = 'private'; break;
        }
    }
    return $post;
}
```